# How to multithread two singleton browsers on Selenium Grid?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, singleton, selenium-grid

I'm building a project and stumbled upon multithreading with Selenium Grid. I have two browser set-ups extending selenium wrapper page that I need to run (Chrome driver & Firefox driver).

I have read a lot of articles on multithreading and singleton pattern separately but don't know how to make them work together.

testng:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="selenium" verbose="1" thread-count="2"  parallel="tests">
    <test name="ChromeTest">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="Run.CucumberRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="FirefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="Run.CucumberRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

cucumber runner:

```java
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "Run",
        plugin = "io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm"
)
public class CucumberRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(CucumberRunner.class);

    @Parameters({"browserName"})
    @BeforeTest()
    public void setUp(String browserName) {

        if (browserName.equals("chrome")){
            CustomChromeDriver chromeDriver = CustomChromeDriver.getInstance();
        } else if (browserName.equals("firefox")){
            CustomFirefoxDriver firefoxDriver = CustomFirefoxDriver.getInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

one of browser instances:

```java
class CustomChromeDriver extends BasicDriver {

    private String HUB = "http://192.168.2.105:4444/wd/hub";

    private WebDriverWait wait;

    private static CustomChromeDriver chrome;

    public static CustomChromeDriver getInstance() {
        if (chrome == null) {
            chrome = new CustomChromeDriver();
        }
        return chrome;
    }

    private CustomChromeDriver() {

        wait = new WebDriverWait(remoteWebDriver, 10);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "bin/chromedriver.exe");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");

        try {
            remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(HUB), capabilities);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        }
    }

}
```

step defs:

```java
public class StepDefinitions {

    private MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(StepDefinitions.class);

    private String testHost = "https://www.google.com/gmail/";


    @Step ("Opening test host")
    @Given("test host open")
    public void openHost() {
        mainPage.navigate(this.testHost);
        LOG.debug("Test host opened");
    }
```

page objects' parent page

```java
public abstract class BasicPage {


    public BasicDriver basicDriver;


    public void navigate(String url) {
        basicDriver.get(url);
    }


    public void shutDown(){
        basicDriver.close();
    }

}
```

stacktrace snippet:

```sh
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at Run.CustomChromeDriver.<init>(CustomChromeDriver.java:49)
    at Run.CustomChromeDriver.getInstance(CustomChromeDriver.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The main problem of your script is that you're trying 
   to instantiate [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) by providing `remoteWebDriver` instance which has not been initialized yet.
2. Consider removing [`static`](https://javapapers.com/core-java/explain-the-java-static-modifier/) access modifier from any classes which assume [WebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) and derivatives usage
3. Consider putting WebDriver and all entities which are not [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) into [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

More information:  [Parallel Tests - Best Practices](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices)

Answer (score 0):

You are using remoteWebDriver before instantiating it

The below block

```
try {
        remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(HUB), capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    }
```

should come before this line

```
 wait = new WebDriverWait(remoteWebDriver, 10);
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "bin/chromedriver.exe");
```

Since remoteWebDriver is not instantiated, you get NullPointerException.